# How to return type of Class for parameterized type

Tags: java

My first try is like this:

```
@Override
public Class<? extends Set<Measurement>> getType() {
    Set<Measurement> s = new HashSet<Measurement>();
    return s.getClass();
}
```

But it does not compile:

> incompatible types: java.lang.Class*java.util.Set* cannot be converted to java.lang.Class*? extends java.util.Set*mydomain.Measurement**

My second try:

```
@Override
public Class<? extends Set<Measurement>> getType() {
    return Set<Measurement>.class;
}
```

Still it does not compile:

> Cannot select from parameterized type

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), I can't see it being useful

Comment: Yes, type erasure is the term :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this by extending generalized class. This will allow compiler to preserve type information.

```
public class So45012361Application {

    public class Measurement {}

    public class MeasurementsSet extends HashSet<Measurement> {}

    public Class<? extends Set<Measurement>> getType() {
        MeasurementsSet ms = new MeasurementsSet();
        return ms.getClass();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new So45012361Application().getType()); //class com.stackoverflow.So45012361Application$MeasurementsSet
        System.out.println(new So45012361Application().getType().getGenericSuperclass()); //java.util.HashSet<com.stackoverflow.So45012361Application$Measurement>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code compiles and runs:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Created by holger on 10.07.2017.
 */
public class Sandkasten
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Sandkasten();
    }

    public Sandkasten()
    {
        System.out.print(getType());
    }

    public Class<? extends Set> getType() { // HERE I made some changes
        Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
        return s.getClass();
    }
}
```

It will output

```
class java.util.HashSet
```

Comment: This is just the same as `return HashSet.class`

Comment: but what if getType should return Class<? extends Set<String>>? (not Class<? extends Set>)

Comment: The `<String>` part doesn't exist at runtime. You can't return it.